# Getting Access Violation 00000000 after a call to an OS function failed

Tags: delphi, crash, stack-trace, access-violation

We have been trying to solve this problem which is causing our program to crash. However, we haven't been able to reproduce the crash in house.

The call stack that is coming from the client's machine is on the link here:

Click to enlarge:

[image: screenshot]

It doesn't seem to have any reference to any of the file in our project, so we're a bit lost as to where to look for a solution.

Could this be an environmental issue? The clients' that are getting this problem is using Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2003. Sometimes, just prior to crash, the customer has been reporting that they have been getting 'A call to an OS function failed' error messages. Can this be related? Based on the call stack, can anyone make sense of what it is trying to do?

[Update] The call stack came from EurekaLog. Also I attach below the call stack from the 'A call to an OS function failed' error, that the customer is experiencing as well. This seems to be related to the AV error that the customer is getting but we are not sure. http://postimage.org/image/jku5dlnuf/

Comment: The call stack in the offsite image is easy enough to understand. It calls Release on a form. Which then calls GetHandle which then attempts to re-create the window. Which fails. I expect everything else you see flows from that. Why would window creation fail? Hard to know what that would happen. I've seen similar sounding errors on systems that had password-protected screen savers. Sounds odd I know. I thought that all stopped with Vista. So it would be plausible on server 2003 (windows 5.2) but not so much on Win 7.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the portion of the stack trace in your image, it's impossible to tell. The stack trace is mostly showing Windows API internal functions from the kernel DLLs.

Exceptions with an address of all zeros is a nil pointer (an object being used before it's created), but there's no way to tell where it's happening from that stack trace.

You should look at adding an exception handling product like [MadExcept](http://madshi.net) or [EurekaLog](http://www.eurekalog.com/) to your application, which would give you a usable stack trace and more error information.  Both are relatively inexpensive, especially when compared to the time spent trying to track down this type of error without them. (My own experience is with MadExcept, but I'm not affiliated with either of them.)

Comment: Or you can use JCLDebug for stack traces which is free and open source

Comment: Hi Ken and awmross, Thanks for your suggestions. Actually, the call stack came from EurekaLog. The call stack for the AV is only showing the Windows API internal functions. However, I attached another call stack for another error 'A call to an OS function failed', which seems to be related (because the customer who reported the problem experienced this as well). Do you know what this error message indicates and why it occured?

Comment: The issue seems to be related to `FormCloseQueryWithEplTrCtrl` (spelling may be off), which is the most recently executed portion of code run from your app (except for the two InterBase related methods slightly higher up, which would seem to be part of IBX and probably not the source of the problem). What does that code do that might access a nil object (if anything)?